# Haproxy Server Statistics page reads server DOWN

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, haproxy

Haproxy's stats page show's that I have server that isn't functioning that is connected to the services. I'm unclear through me search on how to kick the problem server off. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is this a server that is actually down, and you want to remove it from the HAProxy config file, or is this a server that is functioning correctly, but HAProxy believes is down?

Comment: It's a server that doesn't eve exist anymore and should've disconnected on shut down, but didn't. I've restarted the service and it still shows up for some reason.

Comment: You should post up your HAProxy config then.  You probably just need to remove the server from the config.